# What does 'reflection of love for the soul' intend to say?

Tags: poetry, history-of-literature

Source:  [*The Complete Idiot's Guide to Literary Theory and Criticism*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Complete-Idiots-Literary-Theory-Criticism/dp/1615642412) (2013 1 ed). p. 90.

> From the medieval period through the Renaissance, Plato's argument that 
>   physical beauty should be seen as an emanation or reflection of ideal 
>   beauty really took off. Writers such as Dante, Edmund Spenser, and 
>   Baldassare Castiglione, among others, wrote poems of "courtly love," in 
>   which a lover sees his or her attraction to a beloved **as a reflection of love 
>   for the soul**. By contemplating earthly beauty and love, the lover would 
>   draw closer to the divine beauty and truth of God.

I don't understand how you can love the soul? Whose soul?